# Reference to first array element not working in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to change the color of a series in highcharts depending on a particular value given. The code works for all the other objects in the array except for [0]. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
formatter: function () {
  if (op_model == "0") {
    chart = $('#container2').highcharts();
    var series = chart.series[0].color = ("blue");
    return (this.series.name + " " + this.y + "%" + "<br />" + "Your chosen model");
  }
  else return (this.series.name + " " + this.y + "%");
}
```

Comment: Could you show jsfiddle demo with that issue? Thanks.

Comment: sure thing http://jsfiddle.net/niallfaucher/9egt4jjn/

Comment: Why do you want to change series color in formatter? Why not just create chart with predefined color: http://jsfiddle.net/9egt4jjn/1/ ? Of course, if chosen model will change, then update specific series using `series.update({ color: 'new_color'});`

Comment: Users choose one of the four operating models displayed on the graph in response to a survey question, I want to highlight their response on the stacked column chart by changing the color.

Comment: Hi Pawel not entirely sure how to implement your suggestion into my code?

Comment: After user chooses operating model, you display chart. Then why can't you set then that color?

Comment: Many thanks to Pawel, I finally realized I should be creating the conditional statement in the series constructor eg. "color: op_model == 0 ? 'blue' :  null" as opposed to in the formatter initiating another formatter through the use of series.update().

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
color: op_model == 0 ? 'blue' :  null
```

For series, which should be highlighted.